# jQuery Mobile back button on external link causing strange issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I use jQuery mobile 1.0.1 to be precise. I have 2 pages.

```
Index --> Sub Page(external)
```

My hyperlink looks like this:

```
<a href="sub_page.html" rel="external" data-transition="slide">
```

And I have added this code between jQuery and jQuery mobile `<script>` tags:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
});
```

My both index and sub page are full pages with their own headers, content, footers, css declarations and scripts that's why I use external rel.

The strange behaviour:

1. List item
2. I click on hyperlink from the index page
3. It opens a new page, everything is OK
4. I click Back. OK too.
5. I click again on the same hyperlink
6. The sub page is opened again, but after a very small delay(not even a second) "Loading" appears and index page appears inside the sub page.

How can I achieve a simple back button on external link on the same domain ?

**EDIT**
I have solved the problem with this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

between jQuery and jQuery Mobile includes. As jQM docs state: "*we recommend disabling the $.mobile.pushStateEnabled global configuration option to avoid inconsistent navigation behavior in some browsers.*"

Comment: Is ajaxlinksenabled set on both pages?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than disabling AJAX navigation you can just work with it by placing all the custom scripts for each page within the `data-role="page"` elements rather than in the `<head>` of the document. That way the code block will be pulled-into the DOM when the page is brought-in.

A better solution would be to put **all** of the custom JS for your entire site into a single `.js` include and include it in every page in your site. This way all the code for your site will always be available no-matter where the user landed or how they interact with the site (e.g. refreshing pages).

Here's my suggestion:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        ...
    </div>
    <script src="/js/custom-mobile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This generally requires binding through event delegation so you can write code that will trigger when a certain page is added to the DOM. This is important because you can't be sure when a page will be in the DOM. For the same reason you need to be careful when using IDs for your elements, all IDs must be unique site-wide since multiple pages can/will be in the DOM at once.

Comment: I believe such a simple things should be done without any additional JS. It's basic functionality. I can only agree with putting all the pages in data-role="page" divs and I will do that. Thanks for helping to decide